# Task to execute migrations after publishing app in Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

There is the following 'deploy.rb' code:

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart
end
```

This code deploys my app and then restarts my server, but there are some pending migrations after deploy. Can I add task to execute migrations automatically after uploading code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Capistrano 2**

If you want to run migrations everytime you deploy, add in your **deploy.rb** :

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
```

**Or** instead of modify **deploy.rb**, you can call `cap deploy:migrations`, this will run all pending migrations after your deploy

**Capistrano 3**

I presume you have installed capistano-rails gem.

If you want to run migrations automaticaly you can required in your **Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

**Or** just run `cap deploy:migrate`

Sources : https://github.com/capistrano/rails#capistranorails and http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but after 'cap production deploy:migrations' I've got 'Don't know how to build task 'deploy:migrations'

Comment: Which version of Capistrano do you use ?

Comment: Capistrano version is 3.2.0

Comment: I have require 'capistrano/rails/migrations' already. It doesn't help

Comment: Run `cap -vT` from the command line to get a list of available tasks... Is `cap deploy:migrate` listed?  Also, the command is `cap production deploy:migrate` (as mentioned by Yann, not `cap production deploy:migrations` as you have it)...